# What does the weights of Lie group mean?

Tags: lie-groups, at.algebraic-topology

Let $\Delta=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ be the simple root system

of the exceptional Lie group $G_2$ 
with $\alpha_1$ is short and $\alpha_2$ is long, 
so $\lambda_1=2\alpha_1+\alpha_2,\lambda_2=3\alpha_1+2\alpha_2$ 
are the fundamental dominant weights. 
Let $T$ be the maximal torus of $G_2,$ then $H^*(BT;Z)$ is a polynomial algebra
on two generators. Can we see $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ as the generators?
What about $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let *T* be an arbitrary compact torus.
The second cohomology group of *BT* (with arbitrary coefficients, call that ring *k*) generates the full cohomology freely as an algebra. In other words, if you pick a *k*-basis *x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>,... of *H*<sup>2</sup>(*BT*), then you get an isomorphism of *H**(*BT*) with *k*[*x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>,...].

Now let's specialise to the case *k*=ℤ. In that case, the second cohomology group of *BT* is canonically isomorphic to the group of characters of *T*, i.e., to the group of homomorphisms from *T* → *S*<sup>1</sup>. Given a character χ :*T* → *S*<sup>1</sup>, the corresponding element of *H*<sup>2</sup>(*BT*) is represented by (the first Chern class of) the complex line bundle *ET* ×<sub>T</sub> ℂ<sub>χ</sub> → *BT* = *ET*/*T*.

Now back to your question. The elements α<sub>1</sub> and α<sub>2</sub> form a basis of *BT*, where *T* now refers to the maximal torus of *G*<sub>2</sub>. So you get an isomorphism *H**(*BT*;ℤ) $\xrightarrow{\sim}$ ℤ[α<sub>1</sub>, α<sub>2</sub>]. But 
λ<sub>1</sub> and λ<sub>2</sub> also form a basis of *BT*. So you get another isomoprhism *H**(*BT*;ℤ) $\xrightarrow{\sim}$ ℤ[λ<sub>1</sub>, λ<sub>2</sub>].

---

Let me also answer the question in the title of your question:

By "weight of a Lie group", one means a homomorphism from its maximal torus to *S*<sup>1</sup>.